# Recognize 3D shape by its 2D projection

Tags: image-processing, 3d, geometry, vision

I need to restore 3D shape from its 2D projection plot by recognizing it and finding 3d coordinates of vertices. You can see the sample images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prul5.jpg). How can this be done most effectively? Is there any library that could do this? Language choice doesn't matter.

Comment: do you know the size and shape of the objects possible or are they arbitrary? what projection was used (do you know also the parameters)?  I incline to +Close  as apart the tutorial/lib recommendation I see nothing else in your question... I would start with identifying the lines (visible/invisible) and endpoints in 2D. Then  unproject them to 3D based on some assumptions or prior knowledge of the geometrry or cross reference with all the shapes in database ... I am afraid without more specification is this too broad ...